# How do I see and save contents of an array of primitives in a memory dump in JProfiler?

Tags: jprofiler

I have a number of character arrays in the memory dump. I need to see what's inside them. I can't find any way to expand the array.

I use JProfiler 10.0.2, the dump is from a Java 8 JVM, obtained with jmap:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=/tmp/heap.bin <pid>
```

Update: is there a way to save the contents to clipboard or file?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I see now.

Partial Answer:

The contents of array are visible in References pane when you select "Outgoing References".